Visual Studio Code da error al importar funciones o clases
Estoy estudiando Python con un libro (he programado en otros lenguajes anteriormente). De todos los entornos que he probado, el único que me ha gustado ha sido Visual Studio Code.
Vamos a lo que vamos.
Cuando estaba en el capítulo de las funciones y tocaba la parte de importar funciones de un fichero tuve el mismo problema que tengo ahora cuando intento importar clases.
El asunto es, al igual que me pasó con las funciones, que creo un archivo con una clase. Creo otro archivo donde importo la clase (from _0149_modulo import Coche).
Al ejecutar el archivo donde importo la clase recibo un error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Coche' from '_0149_modulo'
La clase está perfectamente realizada. Si me voy al fichero donde está la clase y lo ejecuto, no sale ningún error, y lógicamente tampoco sale nada en la consola.
Acto seguido, vuelvo al fichero donde importo la clase y lo vuelvo a ejecutar. ¡Funciona!
Entonces, cuando quiero ejecutar un código en el que importo una clase, o igualmente, importo funciones desde otro archivo, primero tengo que ir a ese archivo donde se encuentran las clases o funciones y ejecutarlo. Luego volver al archivo donde las importo y utilizo.
Es una lata, porque en esta ocasión, estoy ejecutando pequeños ejercicios, pero más adelante, si quiero analizar un programa realizado por otra persona, con muchas lineas de códigos y ficheros, para poder ejecutar ese programa tendría primero que buscar los archivos donde hay funciones y clases a importar y ejecutarlos. Para luego poder ejecutar el programa completo. Es un coñazo.
Cuando las funciones, lo solucioné borrando Visual Studio Code y volviendo a instalarlo. No tuve problemas durante unos días. Pero hoy de nuevo está dando el mismo problema. No quiero estar desinstalando e instalando de nuevo cada dos por tres.
¿Sabéis a que puede deberse? Estoy en MacOS.
Y es que por más entornos que he probado, el único que me gusta es Visual Studio Code.
Gracias de antemano y saludos.

Visual studio code no es una ide.. es un editor de texto, con capacidades de ide si pones los plugins necesarios.. sera alguno para python que esta molestando??? sera tu entorno virtual???

Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
